# Copy hiberfil.sys/pagefile.sys on a live system

Tags: windows

Is it possible to copy hibernation or paging file on a live system?

I tried to use Hobocopy.exe like this:

```
hobocopy.exe c:\ c:\temp hiberfil.sys
```

..but it does not work.

Using the same hobocopy and the same syntax, I'm able to copy registry files (e.g. SOFTWARE file).

**Does `hiberfil.sys` differ from other system files and is "*more* locked" by a system?**

Is there any way to copy the files without rebooting?

Comment: Related, but too unsolved: http://serverfault.com/q/832381/87017

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a permissions problem, and that even administrators don't have permissions to access this file. Shadow copies of files have the same ACLs as the files they shadow.

What's the particular error you're getting? Can you try

```
hobocopy /verbosity=4 C:\ C:\temp hiberfil.sys
```

And comment with the results? Assuming it's error 5, you're going to have to either change permissions on the file or run `hobocopy` as a user that has access permission. Presumably that's SYSTEM. One way to run things as system (there are several) is to use the `psexec` program and specify the `-s` option. Something like this:

```
psexec -s hobocopy C:\ C:\temp hiberfil.sys
```

You can get `psexec` from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Indeed, the initial error was 5. However, using psexec did not help. It now issues error 0 but nothing is copied: Starting a full copy from C:\ to L:\Temp\h
Copied directory
Backup successfully completed.
Backup started at 2011-03-17 01:05:15, completed at 2011-03-17 01:07:16.
0 files (0.00 bytes, 1 directories) copied, 2727 files skipped

Comment: Weird - it's almost like it didn't match the name of the file. Can you verify that the file is spelled correctly? Also, I'd love to see the output of psexec -s hobocopy /vebosity=4 C:\ L:\Temp\h.

Comment: Also, it might be best to move this conversation to hobocopy@googlegroups.com, since I don't always remember to check back here.

Comment: I thought of another idea: try psexec -s hobocopy C:\ C:\temp *.sys just to see if it can match by wildcard.

Comment: Is it possible to tell hobocopy not to go through subfolders, something like /norecurse? It takes too long to wait for its completion especially in verbose mode while I only need to copy a single file.

Comment: I just run psexec -s hobocopy C:\ C:\temp *.sys and got the following: Copy of file failed with error Access is denied.
 (Error number 5) on file \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy31\hiberfil.sys

Comment: OK, so it looks like the problem is that not even SYSTEM has access to that file. It's possible that enabling the SE_BACKUP privilege would take care of that, but in the meantime I'd try to see if you can do anything to change the ACL on the file. Maybe see if you can take ownership of it.

Comment: As to the question of non-recursive behavior, I agree that it should be there, and it should (probably) be the default. I've got it listed as a feature request and plan to address it at some point. See https://github.com/candera/hobocopy/issues/23. It would be a breaking change, however, so I'll need to rev the major version number in order to release it, with everything that implies.

Comment: I guess I could add a /norecurse option as a non-breaking change, too. That would require only a minor revision update, which is a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Unfortunately, Security tab for this file properties shows "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed" so I cannot take ownership or see current rights.

Comment: Craig, if you do not have hiberfil, you can try on your pagefile.sys, it gives absolutely the same results.

Comment: Hmm. I believe you, but on my system it's able to copy pagefile.sys. I'm not entirely sure what to advise here. I don't think there's any way for hobocopy to access a file that the operating system is denying permission to. The one thing I can think of is that I might need to assert the SE_BACKUP privilege, something I've been meaning to add. Unfortunately, that's not in there right now, and I don't know when I'm going to add it. I'll try to move it up the priority chain.

Comment: Just took a look at this, and it seems to me that hobocopy is already non-recursive by default. You have to specify the /r switch to get it to descend directories. But I agree - it seems like it's doing too much for a single-file copy. I'm tracking this here: https://github.com/candera/hobocopy/issues/23. I'll report back when I get it fixed or figured out.

Comment: If it is not recursive by default, why the verbose output echoes all the existing files to match a mask like *.sys?

Comment: @CraigAndera, see updated and similar question here: http://serverfault.com/q/832381/87017 . This answer doesn't work. **hiberfil.sys** is not the same as pagefile.sys, it seems to be "*more* overly protected".

Answer (score 1):

These files *are* locked more by the system, and that *is* the reason you can't copy them. I can't imagine any reason you'd have for trying to copy them either, the data contained within is entirely invalid except on the live system itself.

Comment: The data is useful for many things. For example, searching through your lost data e.g. http://superuser.com/a/793020/78897

Comment: I can help you to imagine: "Digital Forensic analysis" for example..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, from an Administrator cmd prompt, so it is possible:

`HoboCopy.exe C:\ C:\pf pagefile.sys`

```
HoboCopy (c) 2011 Wangdera Corporation. hobocopy@wangdera.com

Starting a full copy from C:\ to C:\pf
Copied directory
Backup successfully completed.
1 files (2.0 GB, 1 directories) copied, 25 files skipped
```

Comment: It workks for `pagefile.sys` but does *not** work for `hiberfil.sys`. See related serverfault thread linked above.