# Recover Unsaved Notepad Files

Tags: data-recovery, notepad

My computer rebooted when I wasn't home and I lost several *very* important notepad files. Is there any way to recover them? Anything?

Comment: They're gone. Might I suggest a better class of text editor? I'm inordinately fond of sublime text. However, the one thing I've seen that routinely *stops* a reboot is an open, unsaved notepad file, so you might actually have them saved.

Comment: Notepad++ also will create temporary save files for just this case.  http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Restore from backup and forego the histrionics.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you were using Windows Notepad?

Comment: @Keltari, Yea, precisely *because* it is **Windoze** Notepad. 19k views to this page already... I wonder how much data / productivity loss the world has suffered because Notepad couldn't auto backup.

Comment: @Pacerier theres nothing wrong with "Windoze" notepad.  It does exactly the same thing that the default notepad in Linux and Mac do - they dont autosave either.

Answer (score 9):

Standard Windows `notepad.exe` doesn't create recovery or temporary files of any kind.

If you left your computer on but idle for a very long time, there is a very slight chance Windows may have paged out `notepad.exe`'s memory to the page file.  You should power off your system immediately ("hold power button for 4 seconds" power off), boot this system with a live CD, and copy the `pagefile.sys` to another system, and search through it for fragments of your file.

If you are using a Linux boot CD you can try using a hex editor to see what you can find.  You will need to know at least some of the contents of the file as searching through the 4GB, 8GB etc. of your page file (if your system is relatively modern and has that amount of RAM) is impractical.  Also, parts of your file may be in disparate locations in this file and there is no way to really string them together.  Good luck, you will need it.

Use a different text editor if you want something that saves notes automatically.

Comment: If this works...you have no idea how much you'll have helped me.

Comment: @user353817, Did it work?